# Pandas rolling computations for printing elements in the window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a series out of the values in a column of pandas dataframe in a sliding window fashion. For instance, if this is my dataframe

```
    state
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    1
8    4
9    1
```

for a window size of say 3, I want to get a list as [111, 111, 110, 100, 000...]

I am looking for an efficient way to do this (Of course, trivially I can convert *state* into a list and then slide the list indices). Is there a way to use pandas rolling computations here? Can I somehow print the elements in a rolling window?

Comment: I assume each state is in the range 0-9?  if not, you won't be able to decode the result, e.g. 1, 1, 11 vs. 1, 11, 1.

Comment: @Alexander: In my case the range is from 0-9. So this method works perfectly. If we have to make it generic and print it as [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,0]] then I don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = np.array([100, 10, 1])
s.rolling(3).apply(a.dot).apply('{:03.0f}'.format)

0    nan
1    nan
2    111
3    111
4    110
5    100
6    000
7    001
8    014
9    141
Name: state, dtype: object
```

thx @Alex for reminding me to use `dot`

Comment: Thanks! Quite smart indeed :)